# Fastest and Cleanest way to lower fluid polycount

Tags: fluid-simulation, optimization, polycount

As it bake the fluid result is pretty poly expensive because polygons are sync with voxel resolution.

[image]

What's the best way to get an optimized mesh out of a baked-applied-motionless fluid model?

- Limited disolve works pretty fine on planar surface but it takes TOO LONG (1h for 450vx fluid, it use only 7% of my cpu)
- Decimate is far more faster, but i wonder if it's fine to use because i have no idea if it first aim "plannar high poly parts" or if it just reduce polys everwhere at the same time...
- Any other idea?

Comment: I think that there is just to much subdivision in your model :/, try to remove some modifier, or create a low resolution mesh instead. Edit: Did you try to change the preview and Render settings in your fluid simulation panel ? You could maybe change those parameters to get less polygones.